# What should be the value of full path?

Tags: cordova

Is it correct that value of `fileSystem.root.fullPath` can be just: `/`?
Or should I get something like `file///`
I am using android 4.3 and phonegap 2.9.

I am asking because I saw in many tutorials and examples that the `fullPath` is
always something like `file:///...` or `cdv:///...`.

Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fullPath will return '/', whereas toURL() will return 'cdvfile:///'. The method toNativeURL() has been added to 1.0.1 of the org.apache.cordova.file plugin, which returns 'file:///',  as cdvfile is problematic for android 2.x, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6106.

Comment: Thank you very much. So if I want to create a new file called 'moo.txt' which of the paths I have to use? In all examples fullPath will be used. Is this correct?

Comment: I mean blank fullPath... Without toNativeURL or toURL

Comment: If you want to create a file in the filesystem root, you don't want to use either, instead call getFile on fileSystem.root (see http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#DirectoryEntry_getfile)